# Filter out author(s) in SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Is it possible to always hide the commits of one or multiple people in the commit log?

There are some people whose commits I'm not interested in because they never affect the code I work in, and they only pollute my workspace. Is it possible to just not show those commits?

*Note: I have seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/900590/how-to-filter-commits-by-author-in-sourcetree), but that works more like a whitelist filter instead of a blacklist.*

Comment: I think the search view accepts regex, try typing in the not match with Authors selected in dropdown

Comment: I, too, would like this feature. The only thing I've been able to do so far has been to try to create a regular expression that matches everyone _but_ the user I'm trying to filter out. For example, I'm trying to filter out automated commits by a user named "build", so I'm filtering on "^.[^u]" since nobody else has "u" as the second letter of their name.

Answer (score 4):

Yes; on the bottom of the SourceTree window; select

> Search from File Status, Log/History, Search

Then choose

> Authors

on the drop down menu to the right of the big search bar at the top ( This is just above the versions and commits messages are listed normally) and search the authors name; it will list all the commits from that author.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows version :

1. Go to Search View (menu View > Search View, or press Ctrl+3)
2. Change the search filter using the dropdown on the right to
   'Authors'
3. Type your query in the search bar

Reference: Click [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/900590/how-to-filter-commits-by-author-in-sourcetree)